# Looking for a jQuery image modal box like imgBox

Tags: jquery-plugins, modal-dialog

I'm looking for a jQuery image modal box plugin which show loading icon inside image.

[imgBox](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/390/jQuery-Plugin-imgBox-lightbox-image.html) is great but its very old and have many bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fancybox is good.
http://fancybox.net/

A loading icon shows at the center of the load.  You could most likely use css or something in the API or using the object to move the icon to the calling image.

Comment: "use css or something in the API or using the object to move the icon to the calling image." how?